# How do I properly delay jQuery animations when loading a remote HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

EDIT: This software package is the full and undoctored version of what I'm trying to fix here. The problem is in the /data/renderpage.js script. Feel free to examine this before continuing.

https://github.com/Tricorne-Games/HyperBook

I really appreciate all the help guys!

=

I am polishing a jQuery script to do the following in a rigid sequence...

1. Fade out the text.
2. Shrink the size of the container div.
3. Preload the remote HTML ///without showing it yet!///
4. Open the size of the container div.
5. Fade in the new remote HTML.

I do not mind if steps 1 and 2, 4 and 5 are combined to be one whole step (fade/resize at the same time). It's when the new HTML is loaded it interrupts the entire animation, even from the beginning.

The idea is that I do not want my remote HTML to show until after the animation renders right. I want the original text to fade out and the container div close up, then, behind the scenes, ready the text of the new HTML, and then have the container div open up and fade the new text in.

It seems when I call the load(url) function, it instantaneously loads the page up, and the animations are still running (like the new HTML ends up fading out, only to fade back in, and not the original text out and then the new one in). Either that, or the whole function is calling each line at the same time, and it's disrupting the page-changing effect I want.

Here's my current script setup...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Start-Up Page Load (Cover, ToC, etc.)
$('#content').load('pages/page1.htm');

// Navigating Pages
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#content_container').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);

    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.25);

    $('#content').load(ahref);
    $('#content').css({opacity: 0.0});

    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);

    $('#content_container').animate({height: 'show'}, 500);

    return false;

});
});
```

What is it wrong I'm doing here? I have used the delay() function on every one of those steps and it doesn't solve the problem of holding back the new text.

Comment: Apology in advance; I tried to catch up with everyone here and test each person's code, and I may have missed a thing or three.

Comment: Thanks for the full code. You are returning full pages (including header and body tags). If you change your code to `.load(ahref + " #content" )` it will extract only the part you want.

Comment: I placed back the original code to start over, erased my onClick brick to replace it with yours, and the fadeout/shrink works, but then the entire div disappears. With the same `TypeError: a is null` result. I'm beginning to think this is a browser or library problem.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using in your project? The delegated version of the `on` handler is not in really old versions and might cause that error. Scratch that... I see you are including 2.1.n

Comment: Just took your entire project into Visual studio. Added a link on `page2.htm` back to `page1.htm` for testing, added my code and am not seeing any errors in the IE console. How are you hosting the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bunch of the code everyone posted here, I rewrote the segment I originally had to follow suit. This is now my working result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Start-Up Page Load (Cover, ToC, etc.)
$('#content').load('pages/page1.htm');

// Navigating Pages
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.0)
    $('#content_container').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, function(){
        $('#content').load(ahref + '#content', function(){

            $('#content_container').animate({height: 'show'}, 500, function(){
                $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });
        });
    });

    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: According to the docs you needed a space before the `#content`, but that may be optional as it is really just a bookmark link format :) Please note this one does not load the page in parallel to the hide animations, so you are potentially wasting preload time on large pages (only half a second, but your call)

Comment: I brought it back in line, and it works just as good. Again, thank you and all others.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery objects can provide a `promise` for their animation queues by calling `.promise` on the jQuery element.

You can wait on one or more of these to complete using `$.when()` and then perform other operations.

The following does a fade out and slide up in parallel with the load, then (only when the animations complete), slides it down then fades it in (in sequence):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ahref = $(this).attr('href')
    var $container = $('#content_container');
    var $content = $('#content');

    // Slide up and fadeout at the same time
    $container.animate({
        height: 'hide'
    }, 500);
    $content.fadeOut();

    // Load the content while fading out
    $('#content').load(ahref, function () {
        // Wait for the fade and slide to complete
        $.when($container.promise(), $content.promise()).then(function () {
            // Slide down and fadein (in sequence)
            $container.animate({
                height: 'show'
            }, 500, function () {
                $content.fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pffm1tnb/3/

The only issue with this version is that the `load` may complete faster than the fadeout/slideup and show the new data too early. In this case you want to not use `load`, but use `get` (so you have control over when to insert the new content):

```
// Load the content while fading out
$.get(ahref, function (data) {
    // Wait for the fade and slide to complete
    $.when($container.promise(), $content.promise()).then(function () {
        $content.html(data);
        // Slide down and fadein (in sequence)
        $container.animate({
            height: 'show'
        }, 500, function () {
            $content.fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
        });
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pffm1tnb/4/

**Notes:**

- `return false` from a click handler does the same as `e.stopPropagation()` *and* `e.preventDefault()`, so you usually only need one or the other.
- I started with the JSFiddle from `@Pete` as no other sample was handy. Thanks Pete.

**Update:**

Based on the full code now posted, you are returning full pages (including header and body tags). If you change your code to `.load(ahref + " #content" )` it will extract only the part you want. This conflicts with the second (better) example I provided which would need the pages returned to be partial pages (or extract the required part only).

**Additional Update:**

As `$.get` also returns a jQuery `promise`, you can simplify it further to:

```
$.when($.get(ahref), $container.promise(), $content.promise()).then(function (data) {
    $content.html(data);
    // Slide down and fadein (in sequence)
    $container.animate({
        height: 'show'
    }, 500, function () {
        $content.fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    });
});
```

The resolve values from each promise passed to `$.when` are passed to the `then`  in order, so the first parameter passed will be the `data` from the `$.get` promise.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pffm1tnb/11/

Comment: Ended up getting the same error as others suggested I check the console: `TypeError: a is null`, rooting back to jQuery library.

Comment: Is the example JSFiddle working for you? I am using Chrome to test (works fine).

Comment: the JSfiddle works fine (except for a slight padding adjustment I saw when I clicked). I'm using Firefox.

Comment: If you have working (elsewhere) code applied to your page and are still having problems, you may need to list your full page and code (with any new code you are trying). *"There is always one more bug"* :)

Comment: I have added the full software in its original form at the question as a link.

Comment: thanks @TrueBlueAussie , i told you this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're not waiting for the hide animations to finish before loading the content, or waiting for the content to load before starting the show animations. You need to use the callback parameters of the relevant methods. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ahref = $(this).attr('href'),
        $content = $('#content'),
        $contentContainer = $('#content_container');

    $contentContainer.animate({ height: 'hide'}, 500);
    $content.fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
        // animation completed, load content: 
        $content.load(ahref, function() {
            // load completed, show content:
            $content.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            $contentContainer.animate({ height: 'show' }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

Note that for the effect to work the most effectively on the UI you would need to perform the `load()` after the animation which takes the longest to complete has finished.

Comment: This one came to be the closest to the effect I want. But for some reason, the entire div then disappears before reloading.

I'm using margin, and I notice the whole thing adjusts when it's hidden then comes back.

Comment: I threw in another div to contain the container as well, and set its margin to 10px. While this helps stop the adjusting effect, the container div still disappears.

Comment: I have added the full software in its original form at the question as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `load()` function, you can use the [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function and its callback paramater to save the HTML into a variable before actually putting it into the element with [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

After doing all the animations to fade out and close the old box (and maybe inside an animation-finished callback function) you'll want to use something like the following:

```
$.get(ahref, function(data) {
    // JQuery animation before we want to see the text.
    $('#content').html(data); // actually inserts HTML into element.
    // JQuery animation to fade the text in.
});
```

Comment: Same as above. Unless I'm writing it wrong somewhere, it ends up redirecting my browser to the remote HTML.

I set the `var ahref` first to see if it helped.

Comment: @SantoCiaravino I'm fairly new to answering on StackOverflow but I think the proper protocol here would be to open a new question with the new code as it's technically a new question: why isn't the preventDefault working.

Comment: @SantoCiaravino just to check though, did you keep the `return false` in the `on()` function? It shouldn't go into the `get()` callback function!

Comment: Negative; I'm still trying to solve my original problem of a smooth page-changing effect.

I wiped out the entire brick of code inside the onClick() and replaced it with yours and the other person's.

Comment: @SantoCiaravino oh well, there's your issue! The `get()` callback will be called at the moment the HTML data is received with the data as its first argument. Before calling it (outside the `get()`) you'll want to fade out the old text and close the container. In the calback, you want to start opening up the container, put the HTML in with `html()` and fade it in.

Comment: @Santo I have updated my answer to reflect what I said before, and also mentioned that you may want to wait with calling the `get()` function until after the previous animations have finished (using a finished callback parameter).

Comment: Still being redirected. Here's my code...

`    // Navigating Pages
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

        $.get(ahref, function(data) {
      // JQuery animation before we want to see the text.
   $('#content_container').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);
   $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.0);
      $('#content').html(data); // actually inserts HTML into element.
      // JQuery animation to fade the text in.
   $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
   $('#content_container').animate({height: 'show'}, 500);
  });`

Comment: @SantoCiaravino Redirecting is because you got rid of the `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` (although only one of those should be necessary) in the onClick function.

Comment: I have added the full software in its original form at the question as a link.

Answer (score -1):

You can use deferred or callbacks function
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    var dfd1 =  $.Deferred();
    var dfd2 =  $.Deferred();
    var dfd3 =  $.Deferred();
    var dfd4 =  $.Deferred();

    $('#content_container').animate({height: 'hide'}, 500, function(){
        dfd1.resolve();
    });

    dfd1.done(function() {
       $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.25, function() {
            dfd2.resolve();
       });
    });

    dfd2.done(function() {
        $('#content').load(ahref, function() {
            $('#content').css({opacity: 0.0});
            dfd3.resolve();
        });
    });

    dfd3.done(function() {
        $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1.0, function() {
            dfd4.resolve();
        });
    });

    dfd4.done(function() {
        $('#content_container').animate({height: 'show'}, 500);
    });


    return false;

});
```

Comment: Half of this is pointless code as you can get an animation queue promise direct from any element using `promise()`! This is not a good example of how to chain deferreds.

Comment: i didn't get you @TrueBlueAussie, could you please edit my answer what you want to say..

Comment: Quite simply, this is not how you use `deferreds`. You have added a lot of complexity without any real gain. With animation, you can use `.promise()` e.g. `$('#content').fadeTo('slow', 0.25).promise().done(function(){next operation});` or simply chain promises with `then`.

Comment: as per docs http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ fadeTo returns jquery object,isn't it?? and "next operation" is agan async, isn't it??

Comment: Yes but irrelevant. `.promise()` on any jQuery element returns a jQuery queue promise for that element's animation queue :)

Comment: i am little confused can you please update my answer, so that this will help me and others too.

Comment: Your code would require a complete re-write. if an answer is not accepted (e.g. Rory McCrossan's), I will consider writing a *promise-based* one.

Comment: Pete also left a good version of the script, but for some reason the remote HTML won't even render after I took the script, letter for letter.

Comment: As *promised*, I have added an answer that use `promises` ;)

Comment: I have added the full software in its original form at the question as a link.